Sodium batteries - How to manage batteries without a dedicated controller/monitor?
I have recently been reading and hearing plenty about sodium and sodium-ion batteries. From what I understand, they are the next big battery technology. As sodium-based batteries have a completely different chemistry to lithium, NiCd and NiMh batteries, it would make sense that there would be a specialist charge controller chip. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any specialist ICs for this battery chemistry, so the next best method (I would figure) would be to make a sodium-based discrete circuit from scratch.
Are there any charge controllers that could be adapted for sodium/sodium-ion batteries?
If not, where would one start in designing a charge controller circuit for a sodium-based battery chemistry?

Start by writing down the actual requirements for such a controller. What does it need to do?

As sodium-ion batteries are not currently available to consumers, there wouldn't be much point in making charge controllers available to consumers, would there?

Much of this will depend on the exact battery, its chemistry and how it's constructed.  I don't think you can make a "general" sodium battery charge controller, at least until the market develops and commercial batteries become available.

You can buy sodium ion batteries

There are dedicated sodium-ion battery (钠离子电池) charging chips available (or at least announced), for example the CM1901AN.

Looks to me like they'll work okay with an ordinary lithium battery charging circuit, maybe not optimal, but confirm that. They're not going to be used in portable applications where performance is paramount anyway.
For applications such as EV and grid storage, of course, there are other solutions using common components. Anything a dedicated charging chip can do can be accomplished by other means, at some potential cost in complexity and perhaps cost.
Even though these cells currently have inferior energy density compared to lithium cells, I can imagine mass markets for them due to cost and possibly other factors, even in portable electronics. For example, a 3000mAh cell is available at retail in China in 26700 (26mm diameter x 70mm long) size- rather large for the capacity- but for only 9 yuan.

Sodium-ion cells are quite similar to Li-ion cells. They both use the
"rocking-chair" technology of intercalation. They have a similar voltage range, though the range is wider in Na-ion cells.

{Source: Roberts, Kendrick, The re-emergence of sodium ion batteries: Testing, processing, and manufacturability}
Na-Ion cells use the same CCCV charging profile as Li-ion cells do. A configurable Li-ion charger can be configured for the appropriate top voltage.
On a related note, BMSs for use the very same configurable ICs in Na-ion batteries as we do in Li-ion batteries. The BMSs are configured for a wider voltage range than for Li-ion, but that is not an issue for these ICs. (It would be an issue for single-cell Li-ion protector ICs for consumer toys because they are not configurable.) The front-end analog ICs have an input voltage range of 0 to 5 V, which is plenty for a Na-ion cell. The limits are set in a microcontroller, not in the front-end analog IC, and are configurable.
To the comment that these cells are not yet available I say that they are indeed available in small cylindrical form factor.

Also in larger, rectangular prism form factors:
https://gokwh.com/sodium-ion-batteries/

@MrGerber: TIL, thank you.
